# ¿Cómo convertir un objeto a string preservando las funciones que contiene este?

Tags: javascript

Intento convertir un objeto a un string, usando el método `JSON.stringify`, este pierde las funciones que contiene adentro

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({
  any:"..",
  func() {
    console.log("a");
  }
})); // {"any":".."}
```

Esto porque las funciones no son válidas en una estructura JSON. Intenté sobrescribir el método `JSON.stringify` y funciona, pero cuando hay múltiples objetos anidados, los valores de algunas keys son `[object Object]`.

Esto es lo que tengo

```js
JSON.stringify = function(o) {
    const isObject = o => o && Object.prototype.toString.call(o).toLowerCase() === "[object object]";
    let result = '';
    if (o instanceof Array) {
        result += "[";
        o.forEach((e, i) => {
            if (isObject(e) || e instanceof Array) {
                result += JSON.stringify(e) + (i === o.length - 1 ? "]" : ", ");
            } else {
                result += (typeof e === "string" ? `"${e}"` : e) + (i === o.length - 1 ? "]" : ", ");
            }
        });
        return result;
    } else if (isObject(o)) {
        result += "{";
        Object.entries(o).forEach((entry, i) => {
            const [k, v] = entry;
            if (typeof v === "string") {
                result += i === Object.keys(o).length - 1 ? `"${k}":"${v}"` : `"${k}":"${v}", `;
            } else if (typeof v === "function") {
                if (v.toString().startsWith("function") || v.toString().startsWith("(")) {
                    result += i === Object.keys(o).length - 1 ? `"${k}":${v}` : `"${k}":${v}, `;
                } else {
                    result += i === Object.keys(o).length - 1 ? `${v}` : `${v}, `;
                }
            } else if (v instanceof Array || isObject(v)) {
                result += i === Object.keys(o).length - 1 ? `"${k}":${JSON.stringify(v)}` : `"${k}":${v}, `;
            } else {
                result += i === Object.keys(o).length - 1 ? `"${k}":${v}` : `"${k}":${v}, `;
            }
        });
        result += "}";
        return result;
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify({
    a: "b",
    test() {
        return "b";
    }
})); // Funciona

console.log(JSON.stringify({
    a: "b",
    anidado: {
        prueba() {
            return "b";
        }
    }
})); // Funciona

console.log(JSON.stringify({
    json: {
        url: "/json/index"
    },
    json2: {
        url: "/json/json2"
    },
    events: {
        hover() {
            e.target.style.color = "red";
        }
    },
    numArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    test: {
        conf: {
            attributes: true
        },
        then(mutation, observe) {
            console.log(mutation);
            observe.disconnect();
        }
    }
})); // No funciona
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te funcionan los objetos anidados porque necesitas 2 cosas:

1. Considerar primero los [tipos primitivos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Primitive)
2. Después, analizar funciones, arreglos y objetos, pero con recursividad, para que cada propiedad y valor sean formateados por la función, sin importar si pertenecen a un objeto o no

Este fragmento de código funciona con tus ejemplos + adiciones en el último; supongo que necesitarás hacer más pruebas y, tal vez, trabajar un poco el formato.

```js
JSON.stringify = function(o) {
    let result = '';
    let oType = typeof o;
    // Considerar primero NULL y tipos primitivos
    if(o === null) {
        result = 'null';
    } else if(oType == 'undefined') {
        result = 'undefined';
    } else if(oType == 'string') {
        result = `"${o}"`;
    } else if(oType == 'symbol') {
        result = `new Symbol("${o.toString()}")`
    } else if(['boolean', 'number', 'bigint'].includes(oType)) {
        result = o.toString();
    }
    // Ahora analizar funciones, arreglos y objetos
    else if(oType == 'function') {
        result = o.toString();
    } else if(o instanceof Array) {
        result = '[';
        // Recorrer para obtener nuevo arreglo y separar por coma
        result += o.map(item => JSON.stringify(item)).join(', ');
        result += ']';
    } else if(o instanceof Object) {
        result = '{';
        let entries = Object.entries(o);
        entries.forEach((entry, i) => {
            const [k, v] = entry;
            // El valor es función y el nombre igual a la clave
            if(typeof v == 'function' && v.name == k) {
                result += JSON.stringify(v);
            } else {
                result += JSON.stringify(k) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(v);
            }
            // Agregar coma si no es el último
            if(i < entries.length - 1) {
                result += ',\n';
            }
        });
        result += '}';
    } else {
        // Opción no considerada
        console.log(o);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify({
    a: "b",
    test() {
        return "b";
    }
})); // Funciona

console.log(JSON.stringify({
    a: "b",
    anidado: {
        prueba() {
            return "b";
        }
    }
})); // Funciona

console.log(JSON.stringify({
    json: {
        url: "/json/index"
    },
    json2: {
        url: "/json/json2"
    },
    events: {
        hover() {
            e.target.style.color = "red";
        }
    },
    numArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    test: {
        conf: {
            attributes: true
        },
        then(mutation, observe) {
            console.log(mutation);
            observe.disconnect();
        }
    },
    // Agregados para probar
    arrObj: [
        {nombre: "Triby", hobbies: ['Programar', 'Jugar']}
    ],
    objArr: {
        arr: [6.5, 8.4, 100],
        obj: {
            prop1: {
                prop2: ['a', 'b', 'c']
            }
        }
    },
    bool: true,
    undef: undefined,
    null: null
})); // También funciona
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Triby.

Comment: @Rodrigo, un placer, como siempre. Por cierto, el `if(oType == 'function')` puede agregarse al arreglo del `if` previo, pero no quise incluirlo entre los tipos primitivos.